# Glob files matching a search pattern and feed as sequential input to python program

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, python

I have these directories after "ls":

```
08-21-resume-numrelblocks3-nqh2-numblocks2-stackonlyFalse-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-uniformxy
08-22-32-nqh2-alpha-stack1-stack2-numrelblocks3-nqh2-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-uniformxy-epsgreedyprobaction0.1-stackonlyFalse-SNA-Truemultihead-nonlinearitybeforeattn
08-22-6-12-alpha-stack11-stack12-numrelblocks3-nqh1-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-multitower4-epsgreedyprobaction0.1-stackonlyTrue-GAT-Truemultihead-nonlinearitybeforeattn
08-22-alpha-stack5-stack6-numrelblocks3-nqh1-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-multitower3-epsgreedyprobaction0.1-stackonlyTrue-GAT-Truemultihead-nonlinearitybeforeattn
08-23-alpha-stack6-stack9-numrelblocks3-nqh1-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-multitower3-epsgreedyprobaction0.1-stackonlyTrue-SNA-Truemultihead
08-23-lstmcell-alpha-stack1-numrelblocks1-nqh1-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-uniformxy-SpatialNeighborhoodAttention-Truemultihead-Falsestackonly-praFalse-qcmFalse
```

I need to feed directories that are on date 08-22 into my program execute.py. E.g.

```
python execute.py 08-22-32-nqh2-alpha-stack1-stack2-numrelblocks3-nqh2-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-uniformxy-epsgreedyprobaction0.1-stackonlyFalse-SNA-Truemultihead-nonlinearitybeforeattn 08-22-6-12-alpha-stack11-stack12-numrelblocks3-nqh1-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-multitower4-epsgreedyprobaction0.1-stackonlyTrue-GAT-Truemultihead-nonlinearitybeforeattn 08-22-alpha-stack5-stack6-numrelblocks3-nqh1-dockimgnegativereward-gpfg-multitower3-epsgreedyprobaction0.1-stackonlyTrue-GAT-Truemultihead-nonlinearitybeforeattn
```

How do I do so without laboriously copy and pasting each line individually...

Comment: Have you tried "execute.py $(ls 8-22-*)" and using sys.argv ?  Or "echo 8-22-* | execute.py" and reading the filenames?  How about using the glob package?

Comment: Do you need anything more complicated than `for f in 08-22-*; do python execute.py "$f"; done` ? (Since you tagged your question *Ubuntu* I'm assuming you are using the default `bash` shell - or a compatible Bourne-like shell)